# Python csv reader multi-character quotechar?

Tags: python, csv

I am dealing with Concordance loadfiles and have to edit them and thus I am using Python for that. The columns are delimited by the pilcrow char `¶` and have `þ` as the quotechar.

The problem is the quotechar, the csv module in python only accepts a single-char quote (there is no issue when I write a csv file).

Question: how can I read a CSV file in Python where the quotechar is multi-character?

Example of the CSV fle:

```
þcol_1þ¶þcol_2þ¶þcol_3þ¶þcol_4þ
```

Comment: Can you upgrade to Python 3? The `csv` module uses the `str` type in 2 and 3, and in Python 3, being fully Unicode aware, `þ` is just one codepoint.

Comment: Actually, what *encoding* is used for this file? Only if the file is using a multi-byte encoding (either variable like UTF-8 or fixed like UTF-16) would Python 2 have a problem here. If this is done in a *8-bit encoding* like CP1252 then all you need to use is `'\xb6'` and `'\xfe'`.

Comment: Python 3 is the cleanest solution.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: actually, that depends on the encoding. LexisNexis (publishers of Concordance) call it 'ASCII 254', which is patent nonsense since ASCII only goes to 127, but that does indicate this is a 8-bit character.

Comment: @Martijn, The encoding used is UTF-8. And yes, I just tried it with Python 3 and it works.

Comment: @user3557405: Your *source* encoding may be, but the *file* encoding is Latin-1. At least that is what all my research into the format tells me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters to be precise, they call it *A**CS**II 254*. [sic]

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: *facepalm*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Concordance file format is 8-bit encoded, and the `¶` and `þ` characters are encoded in Latin-1, really. That means they are encoded to binary values 0xB6 and 0xFE, respectively.

The Python 2 `csv` module accepts those bytes quite happily:

```
csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter='\xb6', quotechar='\xfe')
```

As usual for the `csv` module, make sure to open the file in binary mode to leave newline handling to the module.

In Python 3, open the file in text mode with `newline=''` and `encoding='latin1'`, and either use the above `\xhh` escapes or the actual characters, so `delimiter='¶', quotechar='þ'`.